# IOS url request issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to send mobile number and password to the server in the ios app. Backend team has given postman API like below image.

**Success when sent as form-data**

[image]

**Below Swift URL request failing, What I'm doing wrong here?**

```
  func sendReq() {
    let Url                 = String(format: "http://xxxxxxx/mobile/request_otp")
    guard let serviceUrl    = URL(string: Url) else { return }
    let parameterDictionary = ["mobile_number" : "xxxxxxxxxx", "password" : "12345678"]
    var request             = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod      = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy     = .useProtocolCachePolicy
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    //  params dict as data
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
        return
    }
    request.httpBody        = httpBody

    // session
    let session             = URLSession.shared

    //data task
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

But above API call throwing error like

```
{
    error = TRUE;
    message = "All fields Required!";
}
```

Comment: `(params as! Data)`... how did you create `params`? what is that?

Comment: {"mobile_number":"xxxxxxxxxx","password":"12345678"} converted as data using jsonEncoder.encode()

Comment: Can't you ask your "server team" to look up the exact error reason in the server logs, i.e. _which_ field is missing in the request?

Comment: where did you set the `Content-Length` in your request's header exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
{\"mobile_number\":xxxxxxxxxx,\"password\":12345678}
```

and select Application/Json instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Type` HTTP header:

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

This way you inform the server that you are sending JSON.